# Transform input XML with complex XSLT logic to get output XML

Tags: xml, xslt, jdeveloper

I have a XML data. I need to transform the input XML data into output XML data with the help of XSLT. I need to develop the XSLT from scratch. The column transformation contains a complex logic (e.g nested CASE statement, complex calculations, complex if-else logic). Is there an open source tool which I can use to do this transformation. I am novice in this area. I heard of a tool Oracle JDeveloper. But couldn't able to install it on Mac. What would be a wise step to work on this?

Thank You!

Comment: `xsltproc` can run any xslt transformation. Or are you interested in development tools?

Comment: @choroba Thank You for the reply. Being a non programmer or novice in this area I would prefer to work with user-friendly developer tools to develop the XSLT in order to transform an input XML data to output XML data.

Comment: Consider oXygen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For trying out XSLT transformations, you'll like http://xsltransform.net/ It handles both XSLT 1 and XSLT 2, letting you choose from multiple Java XSLT engines.

If you want debugging, and assuming you're working with Java (since you mention JDeveloper), you can try Eclipse. The Eclipse IDE has [Eclipse Web Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/), which absorbed the older XSL Tools. These provide XSLT debugging.

the NetBeans IDE also has an XSLT debugger plugin.

A very useful XML editor which provides XSLT (1 and 2) transformations and a 
nifty debugger is [Altova XMLSpy](https://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html).

Comment: AFAIK, XMLSpy is a Windows application.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Oops, didn't notice that Mac compatibility was a requirement. You're right.

Comment: FWIW, OxygenXML supports XSLT 1,2, and 3, has a good debugger, and is multiplatform: https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/download_oxygenxml_editor.html